# Command not found in docker image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I am trying to run this command on LSF cluster using docker image. However, I keep getting the error below. Can someone please help me figure out the issue?

Command:

```
export CUR_STEP="/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh"; \
MEM=100; \
export sortedFQ="${BASE}/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/${PR}/${FULLSM}/paire_test_sorted.fastq"; \
export column=2; \
export DELIM=":"; \
export COLNUM=2; \
export sampleFQ="${BASE}/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/${PR}/${FULLSM}/ADNI_1380"
bsub \
-J "${FULLSM}_bbduk_demulti" \
-o "${BASE}/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/${PR}/${FULLSM}/${FULLSM}.${BAMBASE}_bbduk_demulti.%J" \
-u "${EMAIL}" \
-n1 -W 1440 \
-R "rusage[mem=120192]" \
-q research-hpc \
-a 'docker(an/bbduk:latest)' \
entrypoint.sh;
```

Error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for an/bbduk:latest
[20201106_025413] /usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh starting
java -ea -Xmx100g -Xms100g -cp /usr/local/bbmap/current/ jgi.DemuxByName2 -Xmx100g in=/gscmnt/gc2645/wgs/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380^LP6005117-DNA_G04^ADNI_WGS/paire_test_sorted.fastq delimiter=: column=2 out=/gscmnt/gc2645/wgs/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380^LP6005117-DNA_G04^ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380%_#.fq
/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh: line 149: java: command not found
Command exited with non-zero status 127
        Command being timed: "/usr/local/bbmap/demuxbyname.sh -Xmx100g in=/gscmnt/gc2645/wgs/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380^LP6005117-DNA_G04^ADNI_WGS/paire_test_sorted.fastq delimiter=: column=2 out=/gscmnt/gc2645/wgs/WXS_Aquilla/01-RAW/ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380^LP6005117-DNA_G04^ADNI_WGS/ADNI_1380%_#.fq"
```

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
LABEL maintainer="AN <XXX@XXX.edu>"

LABEL org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"
# LABEL org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE
LABEL org.label-schema.name="XXX/bbduk"
LABEL org.label-schema.description="Image for creating interleaved fastq"

ENV BBMAP_VERSION 38.87
ENV BBMAP_DIR /usr/local/bbmap

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update -y \
&& apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
 make \
 gcc \
 g++ \
 libz-dev \
 libbz2-dev \
 liblzma-dev \
 ncurses-dev \
 bc \
 libnss-sss \
 time 


WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN set -eux; \
       wget -O bbmap.tar.gz https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbmap/files/BBMap_${BBMAP_VERSION}.tar.gz/download \
    && tar -zxf bbmap.tar.gz \
    && rm bbmap.tar.gz 

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

## Add ENV for Shell scripts from BBMAP
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
# CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Entrypoint.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash
    PATH=${BBMAP_DIR}:$PATH}
    
    VERSION="2.0"
    
    DATE="/bin/date +%s"
    display_date () {
        /bin/date -d @${1} +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
    }
    
    date_diff () {
        earlier=${1}
        later=${2}
        diff=$((${later}-${earlier}))
        if [ ${diff} -gt 86400 ]; then
            date -u -d @$((${diff}-86400)) +"%jd%-Hh%-Mm%-Ss"
        else
            date -u -d @${diff} +"%-Hh%-Mm%-Ss"
        fi
    }
    
    quit () {
      echo "[$(display_date $(${DATE}))] Run failed at ${1} step, exit code: 1"
      # /bin/mail -r "docker@${HOSTNAME}" -s "${SYSTEM}: ${BAMFILE} FAIL at ${1} (${PBS_JOBID}${SLURM_JOBID}${LSB_JOBID})" "${EMAIL}" < /dev/null > /dev/null
      if [ "${SHELLDROP}" -eq 1 ]; then echo "Dropping to shell"; exec "/bin/bash"; else exit 1; fi
    }
    
    # trap "{ echo \"[$(display_date $(${DATE}))] Terminated by SIGTERM \"; quit \"${CUR_STEP}\"; }" SIGTERM
    trap "echo \"[$(display_date $(${DATE}))] Terminated by SIGTERM \" && sleep 10s" SIGTERM
    
    
    if [ ! -z "${TIMING}" ]; then TIMING=(/usr/bin/time -v); fi
    
    
    
    start=$(${DATE}); echo "[$(display_date ${start})] ${CUR_STEP} starting"
    "${TIMING[@]}" "${CUR_STEP}" -Xmx${MEM}g in=${sortedFQ} delimiter=${DELIM} column=${COLNUM} out=${sampleFQ}%_#.fq
    exitcode=$?
    end=$(${DATE}); echo "[$(display_date ${end})] ${CUR_STEP} finished, exit code: ${exitcode}, step time $(date_diff ${start} ${end})"
    exit ${exitcode}
```

Answer (score 1):

This command...

```
ENV PATH ${BBMAP_DIR}:${PATH}
```

...is evaluated in the context of the Docker daemon, so the reference to `${PATH}` gets whatever value is visible in the Docker daemon's environment, rather than the `${PATH}` that would be visible in the running container. Since the `java` command is located in `/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java`, you have effectively hidden it.

Don't set `PATH` via a Docker `ENV` command.

Modify your `/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh` script to do it instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

[...]

PATH=${BBMAP_DIR}:${PATH}

[...]
```

Comment: Same error again. I removed `ENV PATH ${BBMAP_DIR}:${PATH}` and added `PATH=${BBMAP_DIR}:$PATH}` to entrypoint.sh, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Update your question to show (a) your `entrypoint.sh` and (b) the value of `$PATH` by calling `echo $PATH` just before running the command that generates the error.

Comment: Please see the entrypoint.sh. How do I get echo $PATH? I am running this on cluster.

Comment: There is a typo in your `entrypoint.sh`. You're missing a `{`. You have `PATH=${BBMAP_DIR}:$PATH}` but you want `PATH=${BBMAP_DIR}:${PATH}`.

Comment: Not sure why, I am getting this error now: `trap: SIGTERM: bad trap
/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh: 52: /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")`

Comment: Accept the answer you got and ask a new question if you are still stuck. Try http://shellcheck.net/; it points out a cubic lightyear of simple syntax mistakes.